# Multiple errors (Category, FullyQualified) when creating certificate in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

The command I am using is adapted from https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=39180:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate –DnsName NV-RXIE.novantas.pri -CertStoreLocation “cert:\LocalMachine\My”
```

The output I am seeing is:

[image]

Can anyone help me to sort it out please? Thank you very much.

By the way, is the location correct? `“cert:\LocalMachine\My”`? Where is it?

Comment: Did you paste the wrong link by mistake? Whether or not you should be storing a self-signed cert in the `LocalMachine` store depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: access denied? try run with elevated permissions

Comment: Thank you, how do I do elevate my permission in powershell?

Comment: If you're on windows 10, press [Win+X] then [A] (if Command Prompt opens, simply type `powershell` and hit enter before running the command)

Comment: I got it working, elevating permission is no difference than any other cases, right click on PowerShell and Run as Administrator does it. Thank you guys.

Comment: But where is the cert file? I assume a cert is a file, `“cert:\LocalMachine\My”`? Where is it?

Comment: _Where is it?_ It's **not** a file, it's an item in `get-childitem “cert:\LocalMachine\My”` (run `dir cert:\LocalMachine\My | % {$_.GetType().FullName}` to see its type). Run `certlm.msc` (or `certmgr.msc` for `cert:\CurrentUser\My`) and pay your attention to `Personal`=>`Certificates`.

Comment: Use `Export-Certificate` and `Export-PfxCertificate` to export a certificate from a certificate store into a file (without or with the private key, respectively).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thought with me so quickly and so kindly.